# Slumdog millionaire (11)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 64.000 Euro question:

> I almost quit when I saw the 64.000 Euro question - I can never tell the
>   four of them apart.  But of course,I had already reached second safe haven,
>   I had nothing to lose, and I was already taking home a five-figure amount of money. So I tried to sort them out.  At first I
>   thought the answer had to be D, because he was nowhere to be seen during
>   that whole cucumber thing.  But then I realized that naturally the twins
>   would be together, so that eliminated answer C as well.
>
> I sat there for a good fifteen minutes pondering the answer, trying to
>   ignore the steam coming out of Prem's ears.  Maddeningly, the part about
>   the brother and the mother (from forty-plus years ago) kept running through
>   my head, but it didn't help me until I remembered that it was B who had
>   been out in front that time.  I got so excited that I screamed out
>   "THE ANSWER IS A", nearly giving Prem another heart attack in the process.
>
> But I didn't care, because I had just won - and I don't have to tell you
>   how much.  I must say Prem acted every bit as overjoyed as I was - but I
>   could have sworn he gave me the "fast finger" when nobody could see.

***What was the 64.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with the Bee Gees, but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question was:

> **Which Gibb brother was not a member of the Bee Gees?**

and the alternatives were:

> **A. Andy**
>
>  **B. Barry**
>
>  **C. Maurice**
>
>  **D. Robin**

Explanation:

> * The *"cucumber thing"* refers to their album Cucumber Castle, on which Robin didn't appear because he was pursuing a solo career.
>  * Robin and Maurice are twin brothers (*"naturally the twins would be together"*).
>  * Barry and Robin shared the lead singer role, so Barry was the sole frontman during Robin's absence (*"it was B who had been out in front that time"* refers to this maybe?
>  * The "mother/brother" clue refers to the song lyrics "Whether you're a brother or whether you're a mother, you're stayin' alive, stayin' alive"
>
>  * Andy was never a member of Bee Gees, he was a solo artist his entire career, so the correct answer is A!

Thanks to GentlePurpleRain, as his/her comment put me in the right direction :)

Comment: I'm glad someone could figure it out.  I made all the same connections you did, but couldn't figure out what the question itself could have been...